# Unique combinations with not all values used

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm sure this has been asked before but it's difficult to search for specifically. I need to find a way of calculating the number of combinations of values where:

- the order does not matter
- repetition is not allowed
- not every value needs to be used

For example:

- Using the values '1', '2' and '3', the combinations would be:

1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 23, 123 = *7 combinations*

In this example, '12' and '21' would be considered the same so both are not included.

- Using the values '1', '2', '3' and '4', the combinations would be:

1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34, 123, 124, 134, 234, 1234 = *15 combinations*

The binomial coefficient and simple factorial don't return these counts, and I'm not sure how to calculate the number of combinations using these rules if I had, say, 8 values.

Comment: You are basically counting the non-empty subsets of the set of symbols: if you are given $k$ symbols, the number you are looking for is $2^k-1$.

Comment: This is what I was after, thank you.